# Identify change in group setting with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which contains three rows. 'ID' is an unique identifier for a person. 'Group1' and 'Group2' are group identifier.

e.g. ID4 has been in Group B and is now in Group A.

`| ID | Group1 | Group2 |
|----|--------|--------|
| 1  | A      | A      |
| 2  | A      | A      |
| 3  | A      | A      |
| 4  | B      | A      |
| 5  | B      | B      |
| 6  | B      | B      |
| 7  | C      | C      |
| 8  | C      | C      |
| 9  | C      | C      |
| 10 | D      | F      |
| 11 | D      | F      |
| 12 | D      | F      |
| 13 | D      | F      |
| 14 | D      | F      |`

I want to know, how consistent the groups are. Are the same members, which have been in a group previously, in a group again?

So based on the people within the group, 75% of group A are consistent. 66.6% of Group B are consistent. 100% of group C and 100% of the members of Group D are the same members as in Group F.

This would lead to:

`| ID | Group1 | Group2 | Cons   |
|----|--------|--------|--------|
| 1  | A      | A      | 0.75   |
| 2  | A      | A      | 0.75   |
| 3  | A      | A      | 0.75   |
| 4  | B      | A      | 0.75   |
| 5  | B      | B      | 0.66   |
| 6  | B      | B      | 0.66   |
| 7  | C      | C      | 1.00   |
| 8  | C      | C      | 1.00   |
| 9  | C      | C      | 1.00   |
| 10 | D      | F      | 1.00   |
| 11 | D      | F      | 1.00   |
| 12 | D      | F      | 1.00   |
| 13 | D      | F      | 1.00   |
| 14 | D      | F      | 1.00   |`

Could you please give me some help on how to achieve what I am looking for? I tried `pct_change` but that won't work.

Thank you for your help

**EDIT**

Thank you very much for your help. I tried both with more of my data and still have a little Problem. To make sure: Participants can only switch from Group1 to Group2

Here is some more data and what I want. As you can see (as well as in the tables above for ID 4), it should be clear that the new group 2 `BD BD GH A` consists to 33% of another group, as well as the Group 2 `BD BD GH A G`. 
For ID nine through 13, I want to be able to say, that the Group 2 `AB` consists to 60% of the same people. For Group2 `DF DC` (ID 14) I want to be able to say, this group consists to 33% of the same people.

`ID               Group1               Group2      Cons
0   A001           BD BD GH A           BD BD GH A  0.333333
1   A002           BD BD GH A           BD BD GH A  0.333333
2   A003           BD BD GH A           BD BD GH A  0.333333
3   A004           BD BD GH A         BD BD GH A G  0.333333
4   A005           BD BD GH A         BD BD GH A G  0.333333
5   A006           BD BD GH A         BD BD GH A G  0.333333
6   A007           BD BD GH A         BD BD GH A F  0.333333
7   A008           BD BD GH A         BD BD GH A F  0.333333
8   A009           BD BD GH A         BD BD GH A F  0.333333
9   A010                   AB                   AB  0.600000
10  A011                   AB                   AB  0.600000
11  A012                   AB                   AB  0.600000
12  A013                DF DC                   AB  0.600000
13  A014                DF DC                   AB  0.600000
14  A015                DF DC                DF DC  0.333333
15  A016  AB CDE FGHI-JSHD JS  AN CDE FGHI-JSHD JS  1.000000
16  A017         HD MV APS MG     HD NV ALS BA HDJ  1.000000
17  A018          LA JF NV WJ         LA JF NV OHB  1.000000`

I feel like this is a small step from now on but I can't figure out how to adjust either one of the two codes to solve my problem.

I hope this helps to clarify my problem. I am sorry if I have been unclear about this.

Thank you again very much for your help.

Comment: A is 75 percent consistent right. i.e 3/4 ??

Comment: @Barath You are absolutly right. I edited the post. Thank you

Comment: What do you then think about my solution

Comment: I am testing it right now and will be back in a second. Thank you both for providing answers so fast.

Comment: I believe you're still mixing up the desired directions here. You want to compute consistency from Group2 -> Group1 for IDs 9-13 and consistency from Group1 -> Group2 for ID 14. It is not clear to me when to choose which direction.

Comment: @Pansen you were right, there was a problem with my thinking. Thank you very much for pointing out! Your solution works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `transform` with a custom consistency function. First, create some example data (Note: **G_Source** corresponds to your *G2* whereas **G_Target** corresponds to *G1* in your example):

#### Create example data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

values = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(10, 2))
columns = ["G_Source", "G_Target"]

df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=columns).sort_values("G_Source")
print(df)

    G_Source    G_Target
0   0           3
3   0           2
4   0           4
5   0           4
7   0           1
8   1           3
9   2           0
6   3           2
1   4           1
2   4           2
```

Next, let's define the consistency function. Basically, we're looking for the count of the most common value. Therefore, it is easy to use `value_counts` in conjunction with `max`.

#### Define consistency function

```
def get_consistency(series):
    max_common = series.value_counts().max()
    size = series.shape[0]

    return max_common / size
```

#### Groupby and transform

Next, we group by the source group (G_Source) and compute the consistency along the target group (G_Target) via `transform.`

```
df["consistency"] = df.groupby("G_Source")["G_Target"].transform(get_consistency)
print(df)

    G_Source  G_Target  consistency
0   0         3         0.4
3   0         2         0.4
4   0         4         0.4
5   0         4         0.4
7   0         1         0.4
8   1         3         1.0
9   2         0         1.0
6   3         2         1.0
1   4         1         0.5
2   4         2         0.5
```

Comment: Next time use `pd.read_clipboard` to read the data from the OP.

Comment: I tried, but it messed up the data frame, therefore I used some toy data...

Comment: This will work only for group B but wont let you get 75 consitency of group A. Thats the reason I went for 2 groupbys

Comment: @Bharath I don't agree. You have to define a **source** and **target** group to check for consistency from source to target. In your solution, you check both ways and use the minimum. But the OP's desired output does not match your result because *G2* is the source group and *G1* is the target group.

Comment: No I think its a typo. People might go frm group 1 to group 2 and vice versa. I think OP wants that as an answer.

Comment: I thought so I might be wrong too. Let me wait for the OP's reply. If he accepts your answer then I vote and modify my solution

Comment: People can only go from group 1 to group 2, sry if I have not been specific about that.

Comment: As I said I upvote. I misunderstood the question maybe.

Answer (score 0):

We can use two groupby here since you want to find the consistency based on two columns i.e

```
# Find the consistency of group1 over group2 
one = df.groupby('Group1')['Group2'].apply(lambda x : sum(x == x.name)/len(x))

# Find the consistency of group2 over group1
two = df.groupby('Group2')['Group1'].apply(lambda x : sum(x == x.name)/len(x))

# Concat and find the min 
prob = pd.concat([one,two.reindex(one.index)],1).min(1)

# Map the values to the dataframe by replacing 0 with 1. 
df['Cons'] = df['Group1'].map(prob.where(prob!=0,1))
```

```
    ID Group1 Group2     Cons
0    1      A      A  0.750000
1    2      A      A  0.750000
2    3      A      A  0.750000
3    4      B      A  0.666667
4    5      B      B  0.666667
5    6      B      B  0.666667
6    7      C      C  1.000000
7    8      C      C  1.000000
8    9      C      C  1.000000
9   10      D      F  1.000000
10  11      D      F  1.000000
11  12      D      F  1.000000
12  13      D      F  1.000000
13  14      D      F  1.000000
```

The above solution deals with the consistency of both the columns. In case you want to just find the consistency of group1 over group2 then we can use

```
df.groupby('Group1')['Group2'].transform(lambda x : sum(x == x.name)/len(x)).replace(0,1)
```

Comment: thank you very much for your time and effort. The solution from panson works slightly better with my data but I can't tell you why. That's the reason I accepted his answere. I wish I could accept both answers, since your input was very helpful as well. Thanks!

Comment: Ohk glad can help.